# Is it safe to pop python-websockets messages without recv()?

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

Usually one would simply await the next message using `await ws.recv()` however I dont want to process each message, but get all of them and process the most recent state. Since `ws.messages` is public I could simply pop all messages and process them together. However the docs do not state anything about it. Is it safe to get the recent messages using `popleft()` instead of `recv()`?